# Android: Draw a bitmap on top of another, matrix applied

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap

I have an imageview, which uses matrix to scale/drag an image. Now I want to overlay another image. The matrix transformation should be applied to the combination of background and overlay.

I did overwrite onDraw and used

```
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, matrix, null);
```

whereas overlay is the new overlay, matrix is the currently applied matrix. This works fine. Unfortunately I can't specify an offset at which the overlay shall appear on top of the background. This works

```
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 50, 10, null);
```

but the overlay remains on that position, once I draw and scale the background again...

How can I accomplish an offset while drawing a bitmap with matrix applied?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to create a new bitmap of approprite size where your overlay will be saved with the matrix transformation. Something like:

```
Bitmap overlay2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(....) 

Canvas c2 = new Canvas(overlay2);

c2.drawBitmap(overlay, matrix, null);

canvas.drawBitmap(overlay2, 50, 10, null);
```

The other way perhaps better is to do canvas.translate:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(50,10);
canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, matrix, null); 
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: Uhmmm. Yammi. How fast :) Meanwhile I came to the first solution too, but it showed some ugly effects on the surrounding area of the overlay. Your second solution works perfectly. Manny thanks.

Comment: Argghh.. No, the second doesn't work. If the image zooms, the overlay moves on the background...

Comment: That is because you need to multiply the translate quantity with the amount of zoom.

Comment: Exactly. Already done. But this gives a bumpy appearance. Right now I'm saving the values used for matrix.postScale. But it would be better I think to read them from the matrix. Need to check, whether it is possible.

Comment: Works perfectly now. Getting the scale with matrix.getValues(). MSCALE_ and MSCALE_Y to multiply with my translation - done :)

Comment: Good to know about matrix.postScale and matrix.getValues have not tried this before :)

Comment: Yes, works very well. Here is the relevant part       float values[] = new float[9];
     matrix.getValues(values);
     Log.d(TAG, "ScaleX = " + values[Matrix.MSCALE_X] + " ScaleY = "+ values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]);
     canvas.translate(100*values[Matrix.MSCALE_X], 100*values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]);